# Access Violation when building a dynamic library using FMX for MacOS platform

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey, ddl, dylib

I have recently read from a eBook named "Fearless Cross-Platform Development with Delphi" about developing a cross-platform dynamic library application.  Therefore, I downloaded the sample source which has a Host and Library projects. The original library project contains one unit which only has one export function below:

```pascal
library HideStringLib; 
uses   
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS} ShareMem, {$ENDIF }   
  uHideStringFunc in 'uHideStringFunc.pas';  
begin 
end.
```

```pascal
unit uHideStringFunc;

interface

{$IFDEF MACOS}
function HideString(const MyString: string): string; stdcall; export;
{$ENDIF}

exports HideString;

implementation

function HideString(const MyString: string): string; stdcall; export;
begin
  // manipulate the string to hide its original contents
  for var i := 1 to Length(MyString) do
    Result := Result + Chr(Random(26) + Ord('A')) + MyString[i];
end;

end.
```

Host has a button clicked to call function below to load the library dynamically:

```pascal
unit ufrmHideStringMain;

...

function TfrmHideStrMain.LoadLibFile: boolean;  
begin       
  DllHandle := LoadLibrary(LIB_NAME);       
  if DLLHandle = 0 then 
  begin            
    lblHidden.Text := 'Could not find function library: ' + LIB_NAME;
    btnHideString.Enabled := False;       
  end else begin            
    @HideString := GetProcAddress(DllHandle, '_HideString');       
  end;  
end;
```

Initially, the original samples compiled and ran successfully in both Windows/MacOS environments.

In order to test using FMX in the library, I tried to modify the library unit (`uHideStringFunc.pas`) by adding `FMX.Dialogs` in the `uses` clause and a `ShowMessage()` statement in the `HideString()` function, and then rebuild.

The program runs OK on Windows, but terminates unexpectedly when run on MacOS. So, I ran the program in debug mode and get an Access Violation whenever `LoadLibray()` is called.  The same incident happens if I add an FMX form in the library project.

Therefore, I would like to know, can a Dynamic Library for MacOS platform be built with FMX units? Or, is there a solution to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug you should [report to Embarcadero directly](https://quality.embarcadero.com).